# How to append a long to a byte array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, byte, long-integer

How do you append a long to a byte array in Java?

I would like to convert the long to bytes and then add it to the byte array.

```
byte[] combined;

long number;
byte[] bytes = {...}

combined = ???
```

Comment: What do you mean with concat?

Comment: can you please explain what output you are expecting

Comment: Those two types are not compatible to be added together, and also this is not concatenation.

Comment: Your question is very much along the lines of "how do I add a car to an apple?"  What exactly are you trying to do?  What kind of output do you expect?

Comment: Sorry I've updated the title now. I expect to have the result in a byte array.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use NIO's [`ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html):

```
byte[] bytes = ...
long number = ...
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes.length+8);
buf.put(bytes);
buf.putLong(number);
byte[] result = buf.array();
```

You allocate the buffer of sufficient length, then copy the array to which you wish to append a byte representation of your `long` value, and then call `myLong` to append it to the array. Calling `buf.array()` harvests the result from the buffer.

Answer (score -3):

lets just say your byte array is of n size. Now just do this,
bytes[n+1]= number;
combined[]= bytes[];

Comment: Not only `bytes[n+1]` (and `bytes[n]` for that matter) will give `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, you can't add `long` to `byte` array.